# How to trim characters of match in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi, trim

I want to trim the last five characters of a match in Vim. The search pattern is not a direct word, instead it is something like `foo.*bar`
Here I want to trim the last five characters of the above match.

I tried `:g/foo.*bar/norm $5X`
but this trims five characters at the end of the lines matching this pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help :global` is not the right tool for the job.

With a substitution:

```
:%s/foo.*bar/\=submatch(0)[:-6]/g
```

See `:help sublist` and `:help submatch()`.